# Relationships between three tables with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to make a relation between three tables.

My database looks like this: https://ibb.co/VggWGRb

And these are my classes:

```
public class Equipment     // model for Equipment table
{
    public int EquipmentID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Item { get; set; }
}

public class Car     // model for car table
{
    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Production { get; set; }
    public int Mileage { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }
}

public class CarEquipment        // model for carequipment table
{
    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public int EquipmentID { get; set; }

    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Equipment> Equipment { get; set; }
}

public class EfDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Equipment> Equipments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CarEquipment> CarEquipments { get; set; }
}
```

I found some solution where somebody used `context.Guild.Include("Player").ToList();`

Maybe should I make something like that?

```
public class EFCarEquipmentRepository : ICarEquipmentRepository
{
    private EfDbContext context = new EfDbContext();

    public IEnumerable<CarEquipment> CarEquipment
    {
        get
        {
            return context.CarEquipments;
        }
    }
}

public interface ICarEquipmentRepository
{
    IEnumerable<CarEquipment> CarEquipment { get; set; }
}
```

How should it be written correct and how to call a car model with his `IEnumerable<string> equipment` in the controller?

Comment: You have not asked anythong basically. How to do this correctly is too generic!
What do you want done correctly? What is your issue with how it is now?

Comment: Why does your CarEquipment have a collection of Equipment ? Why does Equipment have a collection of nonexistent db entity Item?

Comment: Seems to me like your scenario is a classic many:many relationship with an interim table to decompose it into two many:one relationships. Have you searched for how to set these up in your chosen edition of EF? Example https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the ER diagram shown in the image in your question, you can define the relationship in EF like follows,

```
 public class Equipment     // model for Equipment table
{
    public int EquipmentID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Item { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CarEquipment> CarEquipments { get; set; }
}

public class Car     // model for car table
{
    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Production { get; set; }
    public int Mileage { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CarEquipment> CarEquipments { get; set; }
}

public class CarEquipment        // model for carequipmeHnt table
{
    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public int EquipmentID { get; set; }

    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }
    public virtual Equipment Equipment { get; set; }
}

public class EfDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Equipment> Equipments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CarEquipment> CarEquipments { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().HasKey(x => x.CarID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<CarEquipment>().HasKey(x => new { x.CarID, x.EquipmentID });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Equipment>().HasKey(x => x.EquipmentID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<CarEquipment>().HasOne(x => x.Equipment).WithMany(x => x.CarEquipments);
        modelBuilder.Entity<CarEquipment>().HasOne(x => x.Car).WithMany(x => x.CarEquipments);
    }
}
```

And now you can access the CarEquipment along with the Car like this,

```
public class EFCarEquipmentRepository : ICarEquipmentRepository
{
    private EfDbContext context = new EfDbContext();

    public IEnumerable<CarEquipment> CarEquipment
    {
        get
        {
            return context.CarEquipments.Include(x => x.Car);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to access Equipment as well, just chain the method like this,

```
context.CarEquipments.Include(x => x.Car).Include(x => x.Equipment)
```

Note : I have explained this keeping EF Core in reference.
This is one of the best source where one can learn how to define relationships in EF Core : [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)

Comment: Thank you but I have two more questions. I installed EF Core but debugger shows me an alert on HasOne() and WithMany() why? Did I correct this called? AuctionModel model = new AuctionModel 
            {
                car = repository.Cars.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CarID == carId),
                equipment = repo2.CarEquipment.Where( c=> c.CarID == carId).FirstOrDefault()
                
            }; where car is a car model and equipment is a equipment model

Comment: I have used Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 3.1.3 package. Can you check once which version are you using? Regarding your second question, I am not able to understand what issue you are facing? If you need to map equipment then try this,  equipment = repo2.CarEquipments.Include(x => x.Equipment).Where(c => c.CarID == carId).FirstOrDefault().Equipment